# String.force_encoding() in Ruby 1.8.7 (or Rails 2.x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, rubygems

Is there a solution to use `String.force_encoding()` in Ruby 1.8.7 (or Rails 2.x) so that it works like in Ruby 1.9? I read something about require `active_support`, but this does not work

$> **gem list --local | grep 'rails\|activesupport'**

```
 activesupport (3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.3.5)
 rails (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
```

$> **ruby -v**

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
```

$> **rails -v**

```
Rails 2.3.8
```

irb:

```
> require "rubygems"
=> true 
> require "active_support"
=> true 
> "asdf".force_encoding("UTF-8")
NoMethodError: undefined method `force_encoding' for "asdf":String
> String.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
=> false
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only thing `force_encoding` does in 1.9 is that it changes the encoding field of the string, it does not actually modify the string's bytes.

Ruby 1.8 doesn't have the concept of string encodings, so `force_encoding` would be a no-op. You can add it yourself like this if you want to be able to run the same code in 1.8 and 1.9:

```
class String
  def force_encoding(enc)
    self
  end
end
```

There will of course be other things that you have to do to make encodings work the same across 1.8 and 1.9, since they handle this issue very differently.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but where in my code should I be adding this?

Comment: Anywhere will do, more or less. Put it in a file and add a `require` for that file along with all your other `require`s at the top of your "main" `.rb`.

Answer (score 21):

This will give you String#to_my_utf8 in both Ruby 1.8.7 and Ruby 1.9:

```
require 'iconv'
class String
  def to_my_utf8
    ::Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', self + ' ')[0..-2]
  end
end
```

And then...

```
?> "asdf".to_my_utf8
=> "asdf"
```

Inspired by [Paul Battley](http://po-ru.com/diary/fixing-invalid-utf-8-in-ruby-revisited/) and also remembering some of my older work on the [remote_table gem](https://github.com/seamusabshere/remote_table).

Comment: Out of curiosity: why add two spaces and then remove them after the conversion?

Comment: That's Paul Battley's contribution... as he says, "The ‘dangerous’ bytes are those in the range 194-253"... if the string ends with one of those, the conversion sometimes blows up.

Comment: Why do you need rubygems? Also, where do you suggest placing the top code? in the controller of every controller you can to use it in?

Comment: I'd say just put require "iconv" once, somewhere, as a matter of style. Good point... we don't need rubygems!

Comment: It seems like this solution can't handle unicode é characters, could that be true?