# rails 3 mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have a subject from an email that comes in to my rails 3 application like this :

I trying to then save this subject in my database(mongodb) as a string field using mail.subject but i get error 'String not valid UTF-8' ??

Anyone know how i solve this ?

thanks alot
rick

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any sample code, but it looks like the subject returned isn't UTF-8 encoded, but your database is. Try using [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001218) before saving the subject.

```
mail.subject.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

**EDIT:**

For ruby 1.8.7, shamelessly stolen from [String.force_encoding() in Ruby 1.8.7 (or Rails 2.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583924/string-force-encoding-in-ruby-1-8-7-or-rails-2-x)

```
require 'iconv'
class String
  def to_my_utf8
    ::Iconv.conv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', self + ' ')[0..-2]
  end
end
```

And then...

```
mail.subject.to_my_utf8
```

Comment: hi i get this error message when i try your suggestion any ideas ?      undefined method `force_encoding' for "FW: Save almost \2432,000 on a luxury Alaskan yacht holiday!":String

Comment: @rick Oh, sorry. You must be using Ruby 1.8 then? You'll have to use `iconv`. See this question for help on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583924/string-force-encoding-in-ruby-1-8-7-or-rails-2-x

Comment: thanks for the help that sort of works but no for say Japanese characters      for example when i receive this text in a subject of a mail (パンを食べない。) "I will not eat bread"‏   and access the mail.subject or mail.subject.to_my_utf8  it comers out like this    "(\e$B%Q%s$r?)$Y$J$$!#\e(B) \"I will not eat bread\""
any ideas how to display / save this properly ?     thank a lot