# How to write "string".encode("us-ascii") in ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to use the "gmail_xoauth" gem and, unfortunately, the gem uses `encode("us-ascii")` for strings, which is available only for Ruby 1.9.3.

I'm not familiar with `encode` in Ruby 1.9.3 so I wonder what is `"string".encode("us-ascii")` and how do I write it for 1.8.7?

Answer (score 3):

The string.encode("us-ascii") method converts all the characters in the string to United States ASCII 7-bit values.

US-ASCII is essentially plain text with 128 characters total. That encoding was common on United States computers in the 1970s-1990s.

The reason you're seeing it now is probably because you're using email. The email protocol requires US-ASCII encoding for strings.

Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have string encoding methods built-in because Ruby 1.8.7 stores strings as bytes, not encoded characters.

To convert in Ruby 1.8.7, see the Iconv library:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html

Also see the conversion iconv code sample in this answer:

[String.force_encoding() in Ruby 1.8.7 (or Rails 2.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583924/string-force-encoding-in-ruby-1-8-7-or-rails-2-x)