# Making character-range Regexp work with Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, regex

These operations work in Ruby 1.8, but I can't make them work in Ruby 1.9:

```
irb(main):002:0> "Café".match(/[\x80-\xff]/)
SyntaxError: (irb):2: invalid multibyte escape: /[\x80-\xff]/

irb(main):003:0> "Café".match(Regexp.new('[\x80-\xff]', nil, 'n'))
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you could use this `/[^\p{ASCII}]/` which will match anything not in `/[\x00-\x7F]/` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/sXlJACAwdS)

Comment: What is it you’re trying to do? You could do this: `"Café".force_encoding('binary').match(/[\x80-\xff]/n)` – at least it doesn’t raise any exceptions, but it doesn’t really make much sense with a unicode string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to capture the range expressed with code points, you'll need to use `\u` notation with the utf-8 encoding header:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

puts "Café".match(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/)
```

The output of the [demo program](http://ideone.com/0pEaBK) is `é`.

Comment: what would be the difference between your example and say `/[^[:ascii:]]/` or `/[^\p{ASCII}]/` just for edification purposes?

Comment: I asked that question myself. Because this way we can modify the range, use subrange, for instance. `[^\p{ASCII}]` is a set shorthand class.

Comment: Fair enough this would allow for range manipulation but in essence what you have currently is the same as it contains the full range of non-ascii characters. Due to the fact that your answer allows for more flexibility I am inclined to agree that this is the best answer to an ambiguous question.

Comment: Is there a method that would work in both ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9?

Comment: I think this one will work. If you plan to only match non-ASCII, you can use the already discussed `[^\p{ASCII}]` class.

Comment: somehow in 1.8 it matches "a"

Comment: Did you add `u` to the regex: `.match(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/u)`, and did you declare the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: with 1.8:# encoding: utf-8
puts "Café".match(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/)  => C
puts "Café".match(/[\x80-\xff]/)      => nothing
puts "Café".match(/[^\p{ASCII}]/)     => a
puts "Café".match(/[\u0080-\uFFFF]/u) => C

Comment: Interesting. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4585339/3832970), I hope it can help.

Comment: @bananasplit the inverse of the answer works well across versions eg /[^\u0000-\u007F]/u will select é in 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.1.5